# Pass data from Ajax to codeigniter 3

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i was looking some post here, and tried to pass data from an api call to controller on codeigniter 3, i need this data on the root page, so i dont know how should i do that!

```
$.ajax({
    url: ' URL ',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify( {
      "var1": "var1",
      "var2": "var2",
      "var3": "var3",
      "var4": "var4"
    } ),
    processData: false,
    success: function( data ){
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href,  <--- this is ok for root page? the controller is App.php and the function its Index()...
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {"data":data},
            processData: false,
            success: function( data ){
              console.log('pass');
            }
        });
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});
```

then in my **controller**

```
$data['data'] = $this->input->post('data');
$this->load->view('app', $data);
```

and in the **view**

```
<?=$data?>
```

but nothing, it doesnt print anything and doesnt log anything in the console

Comment: first json encode the data then echo the response.

Comment: check for the error in inner ajax request

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh ajax error says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 13(…)"

Comment: try,  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>app",

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh--- POST http://m2m.ka/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url();?%3Eapp 404 (Not Found)

Comment: With your current code, do you get the desired url in page source? Check your page source and see if you getting the url you want in your jquery ajax.

Answer (score 0):

First of all convert your all data into array and then use `$data = json_encode($array);`
.
to render data in json format you have to send content type in $this->output object.

```
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

now the method in the controller will start to render your json data.

Comment: Ok ill try it, but im having the following issue trying to pass the data to controller, on console.log prints this ---> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 13(…), i dont know what im doing wrong.